# How to make a constructor for a class that implements an interface

Tags: php, oop, constructor, interface, constants

I'm asked to create a concrete class named Wall that implements from a Color interface and to "ensure it has a constructor and a property".

Problem is I'm not sure how to make a constructor in PHP like we do in C# or Java.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong in my code, but here you go:

```
interface Color
{
    const CONSTANT = "some constant variable";
    public function someMethod();
}

class Wall implements Color
{
    public $color;

    public function someMethod()
    {
        echo "method implemented";
    }

    public function __construct($color)
    {
        $this->$color = $color;
    }
}
```

BTW, instructions require that the interface have one constant and method.

Comment: Well, your class has a constructor and a property. "Not sure what I'm doing wrong in my code" - Why do you think that there is something wrong with your code?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I guess I should have asked more clearly :p is my constructor ok?

Comment: And if the constructor is ok, then how come some PHP constructors are written like parent:: __constructor($var)? (I couldn't find the explanation anywhere)

Comment: @SummerBoy, http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php

Comment: Thanks Ruslan! That helped